# Bash: paste error with process substitution

Tags: bash, unix, paste

I'm getting an error when trying to use process substitution for zipped files with the paste command.

I'm trying to open 100 zipped files and paste their second columns.

When I try:

```
for name in $(ls FILEPATH/*.gz); do 
temp=${temp}" <(zcat "${name}" | cut -f2)"; done

paste ${temp} > DESTINATION/OUTPUTNAME'
```

I get the error

```
 paste: invalid option -- f
```

When I try paste `$(echo ${temp})` instead of `paste ${temp}`, I get the same problem, but when I `echo ${temp}` into my terminal and manually copy and paste the response into the paste, it works.

Please help me fix this problem.

Comment: Can you add the output of `echo ${temp}` to your poste please?

Comment: `paste` takes a list of filenames. Do your `.gz` files contain filenames in their 2nd column? If so, do any of those filenames start with `-` so `paste` thinks it's an option?

Comment: This is what the echo ${temp} output looks like: <(zcat /FILEPATH/file1.gz) <(zcat /FILEPATH/file2.gz | cut -f2)...up to 100.

No lines in any of the files start with a "-". Column 2 is either a domain or a number.

Comment: `for name in $( ls FILEPATH/*.gz )` can be written `for name in FILEPATH/*.gz`

Comment: If the 2nd column of the zipped files is not a filename, then your question is very confusing.  It looks like you are trying to read filenames from the 2nd column and paste the contents of those files.  What are you trying to do with `paste`?

Comment: Are you just trying to do: `zcat FILEPATH/*.gz | cut -f 2 > outputfile` ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok what I suspect is happening is this:

the temp variable expands to a list of filenames retrieved fro you gzipped files.

if the string '--' exists that is telling paste that it should stop parsing the command line for options and everything after the -- is a file to be used.

if one of the filenames starts -f then you will get your error.

try

```
paste -- ${temp} > DESTINATION/OUTPUTNAME
```

EDIT:

Ok from the comment below it looks like you're bash version supports redirection.

The origional error was caused by the -f2 flag to cat.

try 
    echo <(ls)

if you get a result like /dev/fd/ then process substituion works and I'm confused as to what's happening but I suspect you will not get that.

Comment: I tried paste -- ${temp} and was given the error= paste: <(zcat: No such file or directory

Comment: @user1382685 Think I've found the issue. Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot embed shell syntax such as "<(...)" and "|" in a string, since those parts of the command line are recognized before parameter expansion occurs. Everything you put in `temp` is treated as a simple string argument to `paste`.

There is no easy way to accomplish what you are attempting. I hesitate to mention it, but I think you need to use `eval`:

```
# Simpler than writing a loop
printf -v temp "<( zcat %s | cut -f2) " FILEPATH/*.gz

eval "paste $temp > DESTINATION/OUTPUTNAME"
```